# await vs asyncio.sleep: Does await keyword return control to the loop? Or maybe Pythons's asyncio StreamReader.read() is blocking?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I encountered a strange situation. StreamReader in asyncio seems to be blocking.

```
received = asyncio.Queue()

async def read_loop():
    while True:
        received_data = await reader.read(4096)
        await received.put(received_data)
```

Then when I do

```
task = asyncio.create_task(read_loop())
# some time later....
task.cancel()
```

The task won't get cancelled. However, when I add one single line to this function:

```
async def read_loop():
    while True:
        asyncio.sleep(0)  # THIS LINE
        received_data = await reader.read(4096)
        await received.put(received_data)
```

Everything is working and the task gets cancelled.

It's like the await before reader.read doesn't return control to the event loop. I thought both await and asyncio.sleep return control to the event loop.

I want to understand why adding the sleeping function helped. I'd be grateful for help.

Comment: Can you add what `reader` is? Might help with understanding what's going on.

Comment: It is asyncio.StreamReader of a TCP stream, I got it using asyncio.create_server

Comment: From [python document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=asyncio%20sleep#asyncio.sleep):
"Setting the delay to 0 provides an optimized path to allow other tasks to run. This can be used by long-running functions to avoid blocking the event loop for the full duration of the function call."

That's not a weird use case!

Comment: Need `await asyncio.sleep(0)` after `task.cancel()` to allow the loop raise `CancelledError` from either `await reader.read(4096)` or `await received.put(received_data)`.